# extract sub string from a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone explain how to extract the result  from data below using regex

> INFO: AppId=myApp - CompType=logger - CompId=myCompID : Level=INFO -
>   Message={"sourceId":"Data","sourceType":"info","timestamps":{"original":"1543849385073","uiPublish":"1543849385073"},"correlationId":"1543849385073_2272_38","object":{"old":{"mystate":"complete","state":"item"},"new":{"mystate":"complete","state":"myitem"}},"timestamp":"1543849385073"}

**Expected Result**

> {"old":{"mystate":"complete","state":"item"},"new":{"mystate":"complete","state":"myitem"}}

Comment: what is the result that you want ?

Comment: @DacreDenny ^^^

Comment: Personally, I think you want a 2-step process: 1. A regEx to extract the JSON code (the "Message=" portion of the message), THEN 2. to JSON.parse the JSON, and read any one (or more) of the specific properties you want from the message.

Comment: Additionally, understanding the _source_ of the message, and how you are receiving it in your JS, will dramatically help, and could make the solution far simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? Basically extract anything starting with `{"old` and till `}}`.

```
{"old.+}}
```

[image]

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/sQntX1/3)

Comment: that worked! Thanks

Comment: how do i exclude the    {"old":   given there are  two "mystate" in the data above
That means an end result should look like this
{"mystate":"complete","state":"item"},"new":{"mystate":"complete","state":"myitem"}}

Comment: @Leo {"mystate.+}}

Comment: @Leo - your question is off topic, please read [ask].  You are expected to show some effort - see [mcve].  Lastly, ask a _new_ question if you have follow-up questions.  This answer satisfactorily answers your question, and comments are not intended to allow continued follow-on support.

Comment: For a more robust solution, you might consider something more like `/Message={.+}$/i` - then, OP could theoretically `JSON.parse` the result, and extract any values from the JSON trivially.